# IKVM changes com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal to com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal

Tags: c#, htmlunit, ikvm

I used the latest build of IKVM (7.0.4335.0) to convert the newest version of HtmlUnit (2.9) to .Net. However, when I attempt to create a WebClient object, it throws an error saying, "Provider 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl' not found" I thought this was strange because I had included all the needed assemblies in my project.

I then decided to try to see if I could reach this namespace/class and got as far as com.sun.org.apache.xerces, but then when I tried to type internal, the only option that I had via intellisense was '@internal'.

Therefore, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl exists, but com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocuementBuilderFactoryImpl does not exist. This obviously poses a problem when it can't find the right namespace. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use packages with name internal directly. This are internal packages and can change in the future.

The @ character is C# syntax to access names that are reserved keywords. The word "internal" is a keyword in the C# syntax. This means the C# compiler change com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal to com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.

Comment: I'm not calling it directly.  The line that it fails on is:

WebClient client = new WebClient();

The HtmlUnit WebClient constructor is what calls this namespace/class.  What I don't get is why it works for most other people out there and not for me.

Comment: This sound like a classloader problem. see at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader for more details. A stacktrace can be helpful. But this is a new problem and has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @light Well could you explain more of what the problem was and how you fixed it (if you still remember)?